# Compare mysql datetime with php YY

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm storing some user reports in mysql db.

```
report_id, report_date
```

I'm using mysql datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss)for report_date column.
I need to get

1) Today records using php y-m-d

2) Records between a two dates

Using EXTRACT function i seen YEAR, YEAR_MONTH. But i didn't find a way to get the YEAR MONTH AND DATE

Comment: Questions usually come with code, not a list of requirements.

Comment: I used WHERE DATE_FORMAT(report_date,'%Y%m%d') = '20131130' to compare with today date. It is working fine.. But how can i get the records between two dates. As DATE_FORMAT returns the date as string, < and > don't work with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
The starting date is [start]
The ending  time and date is [stop]

then difference b/w two times.

```
mysql_query("select TIMEDIFF(stop,start) from `time`")
```

Comment: I don't want the time difference. I want records between two dates

Comment: I want to compare report_time between start date and end date.

Answer (score 0):

just generate the dates in PHP and let MySQL handle the comparison:

```
$from = date_format($fromdate, "Y-m-d");
$to = date_format($todate, "Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE report_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the php [date](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function to create the necessary date format.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`
        FROM `table`
        WHERE `report_date` >= '" . date("Y-m-d") . " 00:00:00'
        AND `report_date` <= '" . date("Y-m-d") . " 23:59:59'";
```

This would give you all records for the current day.

If necessary, you can combine it with [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) to convert a string to a UNIX timestamp first. date can then process this timestamp:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last Thursday'))
```

This would calculate a timestamp for last Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's built-in date function, so:

```
$query = "SELECT report_id FROM table WHERE date(report_date) >= date($start) AND date(report_date) <= date($end)";
```

You shouldn't need to wrap your $start and $end variables in date(), but it's just in case.

Hope this helps!